# How to maximize Evolution

Tags: unity, evolution

I don't like Thunderbird, so I installed Evolution. After starting the application I configured my email-account and everything seems to work without a problem.

Except for one really annoying thing: I can't maximize the window.

The maximize-button is missing. I also tried it via the window-menu, but even there the maximize-option is faded out. I also can't resize the window (it is possible to make it larger, but not smaller). But as I am a netbook-user I need to either maximize or at least resize the window to fit the screen.

I just installed Gnome-Shell and Evolution starts maximized. So I'd say, that this is a problem with Unity.

So to be honest, I don't know what I should, or could do.

Comment: I just installed Gnome-Shell and Evolution starts maximized. So I'd say, that this is a problem with Unity. But as said before, I don't know where I should look to solve it.

Comment: I have this same problem with Thunderbird 24.01 in ubuntu 13.10.  The thing is it just started a couple days ago without warning.  I haven't made any changes recently other than the run of the mill software updates.  Does anyone have an answer to this question?